# Fake sign with Idid and uploading to cydia repo

Tags: jailbreak, cydia

I just finished developing IOS app using xcode. I want to upload it to Cydia Repo. However I searched around and it seems like they are all outdated!.

I found this deb maker https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/publishing-your-apps-in-cydia-store-deb-package.61937/

But it doesn’t include the steps how to “fake sign with idid or theos, according to bigboss its a mandatory for Apps.

Is there any new tutorial or documentation? Let me know thanks

Comment: Does `codesign -s - Your.app/` not do the trick?

Comment: in mac or ios? also where do i get the .app diractory in mac?

Comment: I never use the Xcode GUI, but if you have an IPA, you can just unzip it and get `Payload/<Name>.app`.

Comment: jas@jas-Mac codesign -s x.app
x.app: no identity found
jas@jas-Mac

Comment: You need another dash after the `-s`.

Comment: like this codesign -s x.app - ?

Comment: No, just look at the top comment.